# Perfect matching in perl

Tags: perl

I have a problem about perfect matching.I want to get the sum of positive and negative integers from a file .Also I want to get dates have same values in the file.

My File:

```
Hello  -12, 3.4 and 32. Where did you
go on 01/01/2013 ? On 01/01/2013, we
went home. -4 plus 5 makes 1.
03/02/2013
```

Solution:

```
-16    //the sum of negative integers.
38     //the sum of positive integers.
2      //count of dates have same values.
```

My code:

```
    $sum=0;
    $sum1=0;
    while ($_=<>) {
        for each($_=~ /_\d+g){
            $sum+=$_;
        }
        for each($_=~ /_\d+(\.| )/g){
            $sum1+=$_;
        }
        foreach($_=~ / \d{2}(/\d{2}({/\d{4})?)?/ {
            $count++;
        }
    }
    print "$sum\n";
    print "$sum1\n";
    print "$count\n";
}
```

my code is wrong.Please help.I could not print above the results.

Comment: You must *always* add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of *every* Perl program you write, and declare all your variables using `my`, as close as possible to their first point of use. This applies especially when you are asking others for help with fixing it and is just good manners. It would also be poilte if you would add some indentation and whitespace so that your code is at least readable.

Comment: In this case you have posted a Perl program that doesn't even *compile*. There is no excuse for that. Please fix it before asking for others to spend their valuable time helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very broken.  It includes lots of syntax errors, and you should include [`use strict;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html) and [`use warnings;`](http://perldoc.perl.org/warnings.html) in EVERY script.

That said, I can help you a little bit by demonstrating how one would parse a file and pull out various regexes at the same time:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    print "Processing: $_";

    while (m{(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4})|(-\d+)|(\d+\.?\d*)}g) {
        my ($date, $neg, $pos) = ($1, $2, $3);
        if (defined $date) {
            print "  Found Date: $date\n";
        } elsif (defined $neg) {
            print "  Found Neg: $neg\n";
        } elsif (defined $pos) {
            print "  Found Pos: $pos\n";
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
Hello  -12, 3.4 and 32. Where did you
go on 01/01/2013 ? On 01/01/2013, we
went home. -4 plus 5 makes 1.
03/02/2013
```

Outputs:

```
Processing: Hello  -12, 3.4 and 32. Where did you
  Found Neg: -12
  Found Pos: 3.4
  Found Pos: 32.
Processing: go on 01/01/2013 ? On 01/01/2013, we
  Found Date: 01/01/2013
  Found Date: 01/01/2013
Processing: went home. -4 plus 5 makes 1.
  Found Neg: -4
  Found Pos: 5
  Found Pos: 1.
Processing: 03/02/2013
  Found Date: 03/02/2013
```

Comment: I think it fails for `-12.4`, considering it `-12` and `4`.

Comment: Aye, I intentionally limited my regex suggestions to just the numbers in his test data, as I was just demonstrating the overall technique for processing more than one regex at a time and was not going to be guessing what his parsing intentions were.  Honestly, it felt a little insulting to be helping someone who put in such a poor effort into their first question on SO, but this code should get him 90% of the way to the solution he's looking for, and will hopefully lead to a better code in future questions.