# Perfect matching is not working

Tags: perl

I have a problem about perfect matching.I want to get the sum of positive and negative integers from a file .Also I want to get dates have same values in the file.

My File:

```
Hello  -12, 3.4 and 32. Where did you
go on 01/01/2013 ? On 01/01/2013, we
went home. -4 plus 5 makes 1.
03/02/2013
```

Results I should be getting:

```
-16    //the sum of negative integers.
38     //the sum of positive integers.
2      //total number of unique dates :)
```

My code is:

```
$sum=0;
$summ=0;
while (<>) {
    foreach ($_=~ /-\d+/g)
    {
        $sum+=$_;
    }
    foreach ($poz=~ /^\d+?$/g) {
        $summ+=$poz;
    }
    foreach (/\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/) {
        $count++;
    }
}
print "$sum\n"; 
print "$summ\n";
print "$count\n";
```

The output I am getting is:

```
-16
0
2
```

I can not get the value of the sum of positive numbers. Could you please help me?

Comment: The positive numbers in text file are: 32, 5, and 1, respectively.

Comment: That does not answer my question. Would `12/34` be considered two positive numbers? (Acceptable answers: "Yes", "No", "Won't happen")

Comment: No they are not considered as positive numbers

Comment: Good! That makes things easy :)

Comment: ikegami ikegami what happened to easy things? :) We are waiting for your solution.

Comment: When I said "that makes things easy", I was speaking relatively.

Comment: What is "perfect matching"?

Comment: ikegami thank you for your solution but the last thing is the dates should be unique

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [`Perfect matching in perl`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24001008/1733163) from earlier today.

Comment: @hobbs: I imagine *"perfect matching"* is *equality*

Comment: you should use a hash to count unique dates

Answer (score 2):

First of all, *always* use `use strict; use warnings;`. It would have found your first error: The use of `$poz` without ever giving it a value. Twice!

A positive integer is a sequence

- Not preceded by `-`.
- Not preceded by a digit.
- Not preceded by `.`.
- Not preceded by `/`.
- Consists of digits
- Not followed by `.` plus digits. (Well, you might consider `4.0` an integer, but I doubt it.)
- Not followed by a digit.
- Not followed by `/`.

```
(?<![\-\d./])\d+(?![\d/])(?!\.\d)
```

A negative integer is a sequence

- Consists of `-` followed by digits
- Not followed by `.` plus digits. (Well, you might consider `4.0` an integer, but I doubt it.)
- Not followed by a digit.

```
-\d+(?!\d)(?!\.\d)
```

So,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum_p = 0;
my $sum_n = 0;
my $dates = 0;

while (<>) {
    $sum_p += $_ for /(?<![\-\d.\/])\d+(?![\d\/])(?!\.\d)/g;
    $sum_n += $_ for /-\d+(?!\d)(?!\.\d)/g;
    ++$dates while /\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}/g;
}

print "$sum_p\n"; 
print "$sum_n\n";
print "$dates\n";
```